# Как создать экран для фона?

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение. Хочу, чтобы при запуске сперва приходила картинками надпись с   надписями,  а потом плавно, в течении 2-3 секунд, исчезала и был переход на мое приложение.

Как можно реализовать? Какие есть способы.

Comment: ну, покажите отдельный Activity с *картинками и надписью с надписями*, а через несколько секунд запустите дрогую Activity

Answer (score 3):

Нужно написать `SplashActivity`, в ней реализовать "надпись с надписями" и в `OnCreate()` вызвать:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein, R.anim.splashfadeout);
  }
}, 3000);
```

**anim/mainfadein.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:duration="700" />
```

---

**anim/splashfadeout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:zAdjustment="top" 
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
        android:toAlpha="0.0" 
        android:duration="700" />
```